# Write to websocket stream

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I am connecting to a websocket server with `tungstenite` [from this example](https://github.com/snapview/tokio-tungstenite/blob/master/examples/client.rs) and using `write.send` [from there](https://github.com/snapview/tokio-tungstenite/blob/master/tests/communication.rs)

```
let connect_addr = env::args()
    .nth(1)
    .unwrap_or_else(|| panic!("this program requires at least one argument"));

let url = url::Url::parse(&connect_addr).unwrap();

let (stdin_tx, stdin_rx) = futures_channel::mpsc::unbounded();
tokio::spawn(read_stdin(stdin_tx));

let (ws_stream, _) = connect_async(url).await.expect("Failed to connect");
println!("WebSocket handshake has been successfully completed");

let (write, read) = ws_stream.split();

## THIS DOESNT WORK ###
write.send(Message::Text(format!("{}", "HELLO!")))
            .await
            .expect("Failed to send message");
```

I can't get the write to work. I get:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `send` found for struct `futures_util::stream::stream::split::SplitSink<tokio_tungstenite::WebSocketStream<tokio_tungstenite::stream::Stream<tokio::net::tcp::stream::TcpStream, tokio_native_tls::TlsStream<tokio::net::tcp::stream::TcpStream>>>, tungstenite::protocol::message::Message>` in the current scope
   --> src/main.rs:28:15
    |
28  |         write.send(Message::Text(format!("{}", 8)))
    |               ^^^^ method not found in `futures_util::stream::stream::split::SplitSink<tokio_tungstenite::WebSocketStream<tokio_tungstenite::stream::Stream<tokio::net::tcp::stream::TcpStream, tokio_native_tls::TlsStream<tokio::net::tcp::stream::TcpStream>>>, tungstenite::protocol::message::Message>`
    |
   ::: ../futures-util-0.3.5/src/sink/mod.rs:207:8
    |
207 |     fn send(&mut self, item: Item) -> Send<'_, Self, Item>
    |        ----
    |        |
    |        the method is available for `std::boxed::Box<futures_util::stream::stream::split::SplitSink<tokio_tungstenite::WebSocketStream<tokio_tungstenite::stream::Stream<tokio::net::tcp::stream::TcpStream, tokio_native_tls::TlsStream<tokio::net::tcp::stream::TcpStream>>>, tungstenite::protocol::message::Message>>` here
    |        the method is available for `std::sync::Arc<futures_util::stream::stream::split::SplitSink<tokio_tungstenite::WebSocketStream<tokio_tungstenite::stream::Stream<tokio::net::tcp::stream::TcpStream, tokio_native_tls::TlsStream<tokio::net::tcp::stream::TcpStream>>>, tungstenite::protocol::message::Message>>` here
    |        the method is available for `std::rc::Rc<futures_util::stream::stream::split::SplitSink<tokio_tungstenite::WebSocketStream<tokio_tungstenite::stream::Stream<tokio::net::tcp::stream::TcpStream, tokio_native_tls::TlsStream<tokio::net::tcp::stream::TcpStream>>>, tungstenite::protocol::message::Message>>` here
```

Comment: Would `let (mut write, read) = ws_stream.split();` work?

Comment: @AlexLarionov I tried that didn't change anything

Comment: `Sink` is a consumer of a `Stream`, it doesn't have functionally like `send`.  Code in the second example uses channel to send data. you can do the same; since Receiver of a channel is a `Stream` you can consume the receiver via `write` like  `receiver.forward(write)` (or `write.send_all(receiver)`), this will route all the messages to the `Sink`, then you can send messages via `Sender` of the Channel

Comment: How are they different, under the hood client_async and connect_async return the same thing? Am I missing something. Could you make an example if it’s not too much trouble? @Ömer Erden

Comment: From your examples; First one using split after connect_async, which provides 2 object to read and write separately. Second one directly uses send over `WebSocketStream` without splitting.

Comment: There’s a split at line 101?

Comment: @Akshat well probably it works because second example [imports](https://github.com/snapview/tokio-tungstenite/blob/master/tests/communication.rs#L1) `StreamExt` with `SinkExt`, if it is not try using other imports also.  Next time please point to the correct line in the question instead of a whole file, it may make question easier to understand.

Comment: @ÖmerErden sorry about that! Adding in SinkExt helps and solves the issue. I didn't quite expect adding an import to increase functionality thats something new to me (vs not working)